# Travelling to the Ireland for non-EU Nationals holding EU Blue Card

Tags: visas, germany, tourist-visas, ireland

Do non-EU nationals holding a valid EU Blue Card (issued by Germany) require a visa to enter Ireland?

[This website](https://www.dfa.ie/irish-embassy/germany/our-services/visas/visas-for-ireland/) says

> Exemptions to the requirement to have a visa for short stay visits to Ireland
>
> 1. Holders of travel documents issued by Germany ("blue documents") in accordance with Article 28 of the Geneva Convention.

So, I'm not sure if "blue documents" here refers or includes the EU Blue Card or is it something completely different?

(Please add  an "EU-Blue-Card" tag to the question if you have enough reputation. Thanks.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @phoog said in the comment, different travel document.

Article 28 of the Geneva Convention deals with refugees. Unless you are a refugee, it does not apply to you.

Furthermore, the Blue Card proposal does not apply in Ireland.

> The Blue Card is an approved EU-wide work permit (Council Directive 2009/50/EC) allowing high-skilled non-EU citizens to work and live in any country within the European Union, excluding Denmark, Ireland and the United Kingdom, which are not subject to the proposal.

This is the link where [Article 28](http://www.ohchr.org/EN/ProfessionalInterest/Pages/StatusOfRefugees.aspx) can be read.

Comment: In other words, "blue document" is indeed something completely different.

Comment: I think the more relevant part about Ireland here is not that you cannot get a blue card or transfer a blue card to Ireland, but that the blue card gives you a Schengen visa, and Ireland is not in Schengen.